# NGINX react app served in subdirectory endless redirect outside server

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router, create-react-app, nginx-location

I have created React application using create-react-app and react-router-dom. I have deployed it on my UAT server using NGINX and want to serve it in subdirectory myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal.

I can access it without problems by Chrome on my UAT Server using addresses like: 
**localhost/MyPortal** (redirects to localhost/MyPortal/), 
**localhost/MyPortal/** 
 **myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/**.

If I try to access the site from other computer using in Chrome URL
**http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/**
 then I get endless loop asking for
**http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html/index.html**(...)
The first request I send is **http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/** 
 It returns 301(Moved pernamently), and adds in response headers 'Location' = **http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/index.html/** 
 The next request returns 'Location' = **http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/index.html/index.html/** , and so on.

I can access from my other computer single files like: 
**http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/static/js/2.3d3c3914.chunk.js**,
**http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/manifest.json** 
and 
**http://myUatServerDomainUrl/MyPortal/index.html** 
(displays white screen, body contains message "You need to enable JavaScript", but this request downloads 2.3d3c3914.chunk.js and 2.3d3c3914.chunk.js.chunk.js too)

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  ~.;

    (...)

    root C:/fold1/fold2/MyPortalProjectDeploymentFolder;
    location /MyPortal/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.html /index.html /MyPortal/index.html;
    }
}
```

App.tsx

```
  <BrowserRouter basename="/MyPortal">
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? require("react-hot-loader/root").hot(Home) : Home} />        
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

manifest.json

```
start_url: "./index.html",
```

package.json

```
  "homepage": "/MyPortal", # also tried "."
```

Why when I try to access my app outside my server I get this strange behaviour?

Comment: Do you have a `index index.html;` line in your config? Try `try_files $uri $uri/ /MyPortal/index.html;` instead of yours one.

Comment: Finally I found the answer, I was for most time wrong because of browsers cache, I had to clear all cache and history and then I could test properly new configurations.


@ivan-shatsky everything was fine with my configuration, and I was also able to make directive try_files  shorter like your version and everything works fine. Thank you!

Comment: It is always a good practice in case of any trouble possibly caused by cache made a request from incognito window to bypass any existing browser cache.